# Redux - Wrap actions inside another action in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk

I have several actions, that are need to be used with another one action, 
more specific i have actions to work with doument and one action to save it, and i dont wont to repeat calling of save document, so i tried to create myself wrapper on the `mapDispatchToProps` and `thunk`.

I need to each action I pass to the method performed to `thunk` actions -

From

```
function changeAction() {
   return: {
     type: types.CHANGE
   }
}
```

To

```
function change() {
   return(dispatch, getState) => {
      dispatch(changeAction())
      saveDocument(getState());
   }
}
```

I tried to create method to map actions to thunk

```
export function mapUpdatePresentationsToProps(actions) {
    const mappedActions = {};

    Object.keys(actions).map(action => {
       mappedActions[action] = function() {
          return (dispatch, getState) => {
             dispatch(action)
             dispatch(updatePresentation(getState()))
          }
        }
    })

  return mappedActions;
}
```

And I always get an error 'Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.' Am i doing something wrong? I dont know how i can debug them. Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to change:

```
dispatch(action)
```

to something like:

```
dispatch(actions[action]())
```

Right now it seems that you try to dispatch a string